# How to store data from 2 file to array and compare tcl

Tags: tcl

I am new and still learning for Tcl.

Now, I have 2 files which having different data, i want to store it into array and compare in result to print the difference of data between two files into a new text file. For example, `file1.txt`

```
1
2
3
```

While `file2.txt` has data

```
2
4
5
```

After compare and found the difference, write it into a new text file, `file3.txt`. Which is to be like

```
4
5
```

Comment: So… that's a one-way difference, describing the _new_ lines that are added but not the _old_ lines that were removed. Is the order significant?

Comment: @DonalFellows yea,old line is significant too so that i can store those same data and different data in different text file

Answer (score 2):

You can use `struct::set` package from Tcllib. Read in the values from the files into lists,

```
package require struct::set
::struct::set difference {2 4 5} {1 2 3}
```

and then write out the result.

Comment: And use `fileutil::cat` or `fileutil::foreachLine` to read the file